# Problema logico de js con arrays y objetos

Tags: javascript

tengo una problemas para poder llenar un arreglo de datos.

Primero lo que estoy programando es para obtener el total de ventas por sector de un restaurante (arriba, abajo y camarin) en un rango de fechas y horas determinadas por el usuario.

Estos datos ya los obtengo desde la base de datos del negocio y los recibo en formato JSON.

Pero el problema es que un turno que inicia a las 20 horas de un viernes (por ejemplo) y no termina a las 00 sino que termina en la madrugada del sabado, se podria decir que a las 04:00. En la consulta original tenia el problema de que gran parte de las ventas de todo el dia viernes se perdia ya que las absorvia el dia sabado a la madrugada. Por ejemplo total del viernes = 1000 y las del sabado = 1200 pero 200 son del sabado a la madrugada por lo que (por reglas de negocio) deberia pertenecer al viernes (viernes = 1200 sabado = 1000)

Yo en mysql ya tenia una consulta bien hecha para que me traiga de una fecha el total sectorizado pero tenia ese problema de las horas. Por lo que decidi simplemente hacer una consulta que me traiga sin sumar nada todas las ventas de ese rango de fechas y horas para procesar y agrupar esos datos en js.

A continuación dejo un arreglo JSON igual al que me devuelve la base de datos con la logica que implemente. La hora de bandera como limite del turno de la madrugada son las 06:00am.

```
    const arr = [
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:00:00' , total:1000, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:03:00' , total:2566, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:10:00' , total:3221, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:10:00' , total:2100, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'22:00:00' , total:4000, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'22:10:00' , total:2336, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:30:00' , total:2336, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:35:00' , total:1226, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:36:00' , total:5662, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:45:00' , total:4566, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:46:00' , total:1566, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:46:00' , total:455, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
  
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'00:01:00' , total:3788, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'00:46:00' , total:3478, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'00:50:00' , total:422, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'01:00:00' , total:987, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'01:37:00' , total:1234, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'20:01:00' , total:3455, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'21:37:00' , total:1234, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'22:32:00' , total:4000, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
]
let aux_arr = []
let aux_obj = {
  fecha: '',
  abajo:0,
  arriba:0,
  camarin:0
}
let aux_fecha = arr[0].fecha
aux_obj.fecha = aux_fecha

arr.map(e=>{
  if(e.fecha === aux_fecha || e.hora < '06:00'){
    aux_obj[e.mesa.toLowerCase()] += e.total
  }else{
    aux_arr.push(aux_obj)
   
    aux_obj.abajo = 0,aux_obj.arriba = 0,aux_obj.camarin = 0
    aux_fecha = e.fecha, aux_obj.fecha= e.fecha
    aux_obj[e.mesa.toLowerCase()] = e.total
  }
})

console.log(aux_arr)
```

**El problema por el cual hago este post es que el resultado del console.log(aux_arr) es este:**

```
[
  {
    fecha: '2022-11-12',
    abajo: 3455,
    arriba: 1234,
    camarin: 4000
  }
]
```

mientras que el resultado esperado deberia ser este:

```
 [
  {
    fecha: '2022-11-11',
    abajo: 22263,
    arriba: 16237,
    camarin: 2443
  },
  {
    fecha: '2022-11-12',
    abajo: 3455,
    arriba: 1234,
    camarin: 4000
  }
]
```

No se porque "elimina" el contenido previo del array. Las pruebas las estoy haciendo con RunDev.

Answer (score 2):

En realidad hay dos problemas en tu código. El primero y más obvio es que en el *else* sólo se entra la primera vez, cuando se cambia de día, pero no entra para el resto que pertenece al segundo día. Para solucionarlo, podrías hacer una comprobación al salir del map y si hay datos válidos, hacer un push de esos datos.

El segundo problema es menos obvio, y es que cuando haces un push de un objeto, este se almacena por referencia y no por valor, así que si luego cambias los valores de ese objeto también se cambiarán los que has metido con el push. Por lo tanto deberás hacer una copia del objeto y esa copia es la que deberás meter con el push. Una forma de hacerlo es convirtiéndolo a JSON y volviendo a convertirlo en objeto. El código quedaría algo así

```js
const arr = [
      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:00:00' , total:1000, mesa:'ABAJO'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:03:00' , total:2566, mesa:'ABAJO'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:10:00' , total:3221, mesa:'ABAJO'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:10:00' , total:2100, mesa:'ABAJO'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'22:00:00' , total:4000, mesa:'ABAJO'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'22:10:00' , total:2336, mesa:'ABAJO'},

      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:30:00' , total:2336, mesa:'ABAJO'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:35:00' , total:1226, mesa:'ABAJO'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:36:00' , total:5662, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:45:00' , total:4566, mesa:'ARRIBA'},

      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:46:00' , total:1566, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:46:00' , total:455, mesa:'CAMARIN'},

      {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'00:01:00' , total:3788, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'00:46:00' , total:3478, mesa:'ABAJO'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'00:50:00' , total:422, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'01:00:00' , total:987, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'01:37:00' , total:1234, mesa:'ARRIBA'},

      {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'20:01:00' , total:3455, mesa:'ABAJO'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'21:37:00' , total:1234, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
      {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'22:32:00' , total:4000, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
    ]
    let aux_arr = []
    let aux_obj = {
      fecha: '',
      abajo:0,
      arriba:0,
      camarin:0
    }
    let aux_fecha = arr[0].fecha
    aux_obj.fecha = aux_fecha

    arr.map(e=>{
      if(e.fecha === aux_fecha || e.hora < '06:00'){
        aux_obj[e.mesa.toLowerCase()] += e.total
      }else{
        aux_arr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aux_obj)))

        aux_obj.abajo = 0,aux_obj.arriba = 0,aux_obj.camarin = 0
        aux_fecha = e.fecha, aux_obj.fecha= e.fecha
        aux_obj[e.mesa.toLowerCase()] = e.total
      }
    })
    if(aux_obj.abajo != 0 || aux_obj.arriba != 0 || aux_obj.camarin != 0){
      aux_arr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aux_obj)))
    }

    console.log(aux_arr)
```

Comment: Hola pedro, gracias por tu repuesta. Si, faltaba meter el ultimo registro pero como no funcionaba lo del array no lo habia desarrollado. Tu repuesta del JSON me sirvio mucho pero mejore un poco el codigo, no se si es mas eficiente pero al menos es un poco mas elegante. Dejo mi repuesta mas adelante

Comment: Cierto, posiblemente el código es mejorable. Siempre me surge la duda de si mejorar el código o si limitarme a corregir el problema que se plantea. Para una aplicación real tal vez sea mejor proponer un código mejor, pero desde el punto de vista educativo pienso que es mejor dejar el código planteado y explicar sólo cómo solucionar el problema. En fin, es imposible acertar siempre. Un posible problema que vi en tu lógica es que sólo funciona si las fechas están ordenadas en forma ascendente, supongo que si lo has hecho de esta manera es porque es así. Animo y suerte con tu proyecto.

Comment: Hola pedro, es que si es para una aplicacion real. Esta es la primer version para la problematica que plantie en el post y seguramente la iré mejorando en el tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Luego de probar alternativas similares y gracias a la repuesta de Pedro logre esta solución, me parece que es un poco mas comfiable por que hago uso del filter con buenas condiciones para poder traer exactamente los datos que necesito en un solo arreglo.

```
    const arr = [
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:00:00' , total:1000, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:03:00' , total:2566, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:10:00' , total:3221, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'20:10:00' , total:2100, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'22:00:00' , total:4000, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'22:10:00' , total:2336, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:30:00' , total:2336, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:35:00' , total:1226, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:36:00' , total:5662, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:45:00' , total:4566, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:46:00' , total:1566, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-11', hora:'23:46:00' , total:455, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
  
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'00:01:00' , total:3788, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'00:46:00' , total:3478, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'00:50:00' , total:422, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'01:00:00' , total:987, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'01:37:00' , total:1234, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'20:01:00' , total:3455, mesa:'ABAJO'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'21:37:00' , total:1234, mesa:'ARRIBA'},
  {fecha:'2022-11-12', hora:'22:32:00' , total:4000, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
  
  {fecha:'2022-11-13', hora:'22:32:00' , total:4000, mesa:'CAMARIN'},
]

let aux_arr = []
let aux_fecha = ''
let aux_obj = {
  fecha: '',
  abajo:0,
  arriba:0,
  camarin:0
}

arr.map(dato=>{
  if(dato.fecha!=aux_fecha){
      aux_fecha = dato.fecha
      let cur_day = new Date(aux_fecha)
      let next_day = new Date( cur_day.setDate(cur_day.getDate() + 1)).toJSON().slice(0,10).toString();
    
      let res = arr.filter(e=>{
          return e.fecha == dato.fecha && e.hora > '06:00'  ||  e.fecha == next_day && e.hora >= '00:00' && e.hora < '06:00'
      })
     
      aux_obj.abajo = 0, aux_obj.arriba = 0, aux_obj.camarin = 0,aux_obj.fecha = aux_fecha

      res.map(e=>{ aux_obj[e.mesa.toLowerCase()] += e.total})
      aux_arr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aux_obj)))
  }
})

console.log(aux_arr)
```